# Can kinetic energy be independent of mass?

Tags: energy, kinematics, conservation-laws

Why is it said that the kinetic energy acquired by a body after traveling a fixed distance from rest under the action of constant force is independent of mass? Yes, the mass of the body is constant.

Comment: The larger the mass, the more kinetic energy it has. But the larger the mass, the less speed is produced by a given force. And these two effects cancel out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work done on a body of mass $m$ by a constant force $F$ across a distance $s$ is $Fs$ and that must equal the change in the kinetic energy of the body. Since the body started from rest, the change in its kinetic energy is $mv^2/2$ where $v$ is the body's speed at the end of the track of length $s$. So,

$Fs = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$

**That** is its kinetic energy and it **definitely depends on its mass**. However, since $F = ma$, where $a$ is the body's acceleration (which is also constant since both $m$ and $F$ are constants), it follows that

$as = \frac{1}{2}v^2$

or

$v = \sqrt{2as}$, which **is independent of $m$**.

So, to summarize, it's **not** the kinetic energy that is independent of the mass but the body's final velocity (under the conditions of the problem).

**Edit:** Following the OP's acceptance of my answer, I feel I should still clarify it.

On a second reading, I think the person who downvoted me does have a point in the sense that if $F$ is fixed, then the acceleration depends on the mass and, by the last expression I wrote, so does the speed. Meanwhile, $Fs$ is fixed so, yes, the kinetic energy is fixed and thus independent of $m$. But that's what I was saying: fixed $F$ and fixed $s$ obviously fix the value of $Fs$ so that can't depend on anything other than $F$ and $s$ and it's the speed that ends up depending on the mass.

On the other hand, for a constant $F$ but fixed *acceleration*, it's $as$ (hence $v$) that is independent of $m$ while the force, although constant, will have to be different for bodies with different masses.

In the end, it all boils down to which entities one wants to keep fixed.

Comment: To the person who downvoted my answer: the problem refers to a constant force, not to a fixed force. Of course a fixed force acting over a fixed distance will produce a fixed kinetic energy just as 3 x 6 = 18 independent of anything else. That is an empty statement. So I understood the problem as one where the force is constant but not necessarily fixed (in the sense that two constant forces applied to two bodies of different masses where the two accelerations are the same will result in the same final speed).

Answer (score 0):

Simple example: the force, F, on a body on a frictionless surface, starting from rest, over a distance d where d and F are in the same direction the work done is W=F*d.  if F= 2 Newtons and d= 8 meters the work done is 16 Joules. Assuming no potential energy containing elements then all the work goes into increasing the Kinetic Energy. A 1 Kg mass would have a final velocity of 5.656 m/s in the direction of the force. If the mass were 2 Kg, the velocity magnitude (speed) would be 4m/s. in both cases the Energy would be 16 Joules.